# Flickering light bug when moving camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, light

[image]

When I move the camera around in certain positions it flashes a completely blinding light. The object that's flickering has an unlit shader graph as a material which is this:

[image: Shadow material] (It's meant to be a shadow edge of the room..

It has a render order of 2 and isn't conflicting with other objects

These are my URP and light settings
[image: URP Settings]
[image: Light Settings]

And my only light in the scene:
[image: light]

And my camera:
[image: Camera]

I have already messed with both the far and the near clipping planes of the camera making them both tiny and ultra massive.